# Does Web development using asp.net and C# need local admin rights

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, c#-2.0

Can you please let me know whether we need admin rights to work on asp.net,C#,VS2005,IIS. Can you please also point out that if we don't have admin privilege then what all are the stuff we will not be able to work on OR what all are the tools in VS ..etc will not be able to access.

Thanks

Comment: This question is better suited for Super User. http://superuser.com.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to run the site in IIS then studio needs to be launched as an administrator to create virtual directories etc.

But if you use Cassini (Visual studio's web server) you can develop ASP.NET in C# without admin rights.

D

Comment: yes I do need to run the project in IIS and yes IIS won't works at all without me being admin. apart, from IIS is there any other point/reason I need admin priv. Thank you for your response.